# Get values only from second request

Tags: java, android

I have a problem i get value from Firebase, but the email only fills up after activity run second time.

```
  private ArrayList<String> currentList = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userTable").child(user.getUid()).child("Container");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String string = childDataSnapshot.getKey();

                    currentList.add(string);

                }


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), currentList.size(),
        //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String size = String.valueOf(listCurrent.size());
        firstNameOfCurrentList.setText(size);
```

First time size = 0;
Second time  = 3(true result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update UI after getting response.hope now it will work fine for you

```
  databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String string = childDataSnapshot.getKey();

                    currentList.add(string);

                }


//Toast.makeText(getContext(), currentList.size(),
    //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String size = String.valueOf(listCurrent.size());
    firstNameOfCurrentList.setText(size);



            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase listener is async, which means it will run in the background and not stop the code until you recieve a response.
In your code you don't wait for the value to be returned from the server, that why  size=0.
what you need to do is check the size inside the listener and after the for loop :

```
 for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String string = childDataSnapshot.getKey();
      currentList.add(string);
  }

String size = String.valueOf(listCurrent.size());
firstNameOfCurrentList.setText(size);
```

This way you will wait for the value to be returned from firebase and then get the list size.